# Cannot POST/ GET request on IBM watson NLU API explorer

Tags: api, nlp, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I am trying to use watson NLU API explorer to check the sample response

https://watson-api-explorer.ng.bluemix.net/apis/natural-language-understanding-v1?cm_mc_uid=16340353563215385786512&cm_mc_sid_50200000=72704601539271513410&cm_mc_sid_52640000=49125901539272322407

Before i click 'Try it out' button i gave the basic authentication for the question with username and password and it is accepted as well.

but whenever i click 'Try it out' button there is a chrome pop up which asks for my credentials. Though i give my correct credentials. It keeps asking my credentials forever. Not sure why is this.

I tried both in chrome and IE.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: chrome popup]

Answer (score 0):

To try out the basics of the API, you don't need to provide a username or password.

However, the API explorer is deprecated and will be removed soon.
You can also explore the [API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/) and the [NLU Demo](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.ng.bluemix.net/). Both have example JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

Allen is correct, this will be removed soon and you should use those links he provided.

In reference to your question, I have not been asked for credentials yet as I've tried to reproduce this. But, some solutions you could try are:

- Try clearing the cache and see if it helps, or try it in in-Private mode
- Make sure this is the case for the `GET` and `POST` portion of the explorer
- Press cancel when it shows the dialogue instead of giving credentials
- Check to see if the response is being generated and the credentials prompt is just a superfluous pop-up
- Give a clear explanation in this issue of how to reproduce your issue (all fields you changed after going to a specific URL)

I hope this helps.